# System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

Tags: soql, query, governorlimits, limits

I am getting an error in a test class

> System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001

Here is the line in the code. There are not 50,000 ProductCategoryMappings, only ~4,400.
Seems I am misunderstanding the nature of the limit. Can someone assist and explain why I am hitting the limit? Thanks.

```
List<Product_Category_Mapping__c> listOfProductCategoryMappings = new List<Product_Category_Mapping__c>(
            [SELECT Id, Segment__c, Site__c, Product_Name__c, Product_Category__c,
                Product_SubCategory__c, Product_Cat_SubCat__c, Product_Type__c 
            FROM Product_Category_Mapping__c]);
```

Comment: The 50000 row limit for queries isn't just for a single query, it's for the entire transaction. This query just happened to be the one to put you over. In a test class, that covers the execution of a single test method (placing code between`Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` gives that code a separate set of limits).

Comment: Are there other queries that run in the same transaction? The governor limits apply to the combined total records retrieved by all queries in the Apex transaction.

Comment: Hitting the query row limit also suggests that you may be using `@isTest(seeAllData=true)`, which, if true, is poor form. A big part of the usefulness of unit tests in Apex is that you're (by default) testing in an environment where test data is isolated from real data.